# BibTeX: Missing chapter titles in reference list

Tags: bibtex

I'm using the `@inbook` command to organize chapter references in books. Here is one of my BibTeX entries:

```
@INBOOK{Ghosal10,
  author =       {S. Ghosal},
  editor =       {N. L. Hjort and C. Holmes and P. M{\"u}ller and S. G. Walker},
  chapter =      {{The {D}irichlet process, related priors and posterior asymptotics}},
  title =        {Bayesian Nonparametrics},
  pages =        {35-79},
  publisher =    {Cambridge University Press},
  year =         {2010},
  address =      {Cambridge},
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, however, as what I get in my references list looks something like this:

> Ghosal, S. (2010). Bayesian nonparametrics. In N. L. Hjort, C. Holmes, P. Muller, & S. G. Walker (Eds.), (p. 35-79). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

I'm using the apacite bibliography style.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: We might... if you provide the community with some context in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: "This doesn't seem to be working" is, I'm afraid, not a particularly illuminating diagnostic message. Please show us an example of an entry of type `@inbook`, and please also tell us which bibliography style you use.

Comment: Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation, I gather that `chapter` should contain the chapter number. Instead you should use `title` for the chapter title and `booktitle` for the title of the collection.

[image]

However, using the `chapter` field doesn't seem to give different output.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Ghosal10,
  author =       {S. Ghosal},
  editor =       {N. L. Hjort and C. Holmes and P. M{\"u}ller and S. G. Walker},
  title =        {{The {D}irichlet process, related priors and posterior asymptotics}},
  booktitle =    {Bayesian Nonparametrics},
  pages =        {35-79},
  publisher =    {Cambridge University Press},
  year =         {2010},
  address =      {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\cite{Ghosal10}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The "booktitle" command makes all the difference.

Thanks for your help.